# How to change a label outside of Popup in kivy python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I know how to change label in kivy.But this time, I need to change my label in the main window from popup box. I tried many ways and looked for the solution as much as I can.For your understand of my problem, please check these line of code..

```
    def targetID(self, tID, value):
        self.yourLbl.text = value[0]
        print(self.yourLbl.text)
```

Let's say value[0] is 'hello world'.
and I assigned its value to self.yourLbl.text.
And print out the label's text,It gives me back 'hello world' as I excepted.

But,The problem is that the label does not change its text to 'hello world'.

Thanks in advance.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyLayout>:
    yourLbl: yourLbl
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        padding: '20dp'
        MDGridLayout:
            md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            adaptive_height: True
            cols: 1
            MDLabel:
                id: yourLbl
                text: 'hello'
                size: self.texture_size

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Choose File'
        md_bg_color: 1, 0, 0, .6
        on_release: Factory.Content().open()


<Content>:
    size_hint: .7, .7
    # background_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: '20dp'
        md_bg_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        ScrollView:
            MDGridLayout:
                adaptive_height: True
                cols: 1
                MDLabel:
                    id: myL
                    text: 'Hello'
        MDFlatButton:
            adaptive_height: True
            text: 'OK'
            on_release: Factory.MyLayout().targetID('yourLbl', file_chooser.selection)
        FileChooserIconView:
            id: file_chooser
            on_selection: root.selected(file_chooser.selection)


    

'''

Builder.load_string(KV)


class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def targetID(self, tID, value):
        self.yourLbl.text = value[0]
        print(self.yourLbl.text)

        # for key, val in self.ids.items():
        #     print('Key={0}, val={1}'.format(key, val))
        #     if key == tID:
        #         print(val.text)
        #         # val.text = value[0]
        #         self.txt = value[0]
        #         print(val.text)



class Content(Popup):
    def close(self):
        self.dismiss()

    def selected(self, filename):
        try:
            self.ids.myL.text = filename[0]
        except:
            pass



class FileChooserApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    FileChooserApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the target `Label` using static method `get_running_app` as follows,

First in `.kv`,

```py
        ...
        MDFlatButton:
            adaptive_height: True
            text: 'OK'
            on_release:
                root.confirm_selection(file_chooser.selection)
            ...
```

Then in method `confirm_selection`,

```py
    def confirm_selection(self, filename):
        # Access the root first.
        root = MDApp.get_running_app().root
        # Now access the target label.
        yourLbl = root.ids.yourLbl
        try:
            yourLbl.text = filename[0]
            self.dismiss()
        except IndexError:
            pass
```